# Itunes connect - Trade name?

Tags: ios, app-store

I can´t find anything on the field "trade name" on the web. It appears as a non-changeable field when creating a new app in itunes connect. I just have short question on this field:

1. Is it the same as the "company name"? That means, will it appear under the app name in the app store?
2. What if the developer is not the owner of the project, like a company developing apps for customers. Would the common company/trade name on the appstore be in this case the owner(customer), or the developers name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No 1. **Trade name** can be the same with company name and it also can be different. If I am not mistaken trade name is the one that appears on the appstore, not the company name.

> For example, the company Panda Chemical Manufacturers, Inc. may use
>   the more friendly trade name Panda Pharmaceuticals when it holds
>   itself out to the public.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_name

No 2. Normally, in this case (at least from the projects that I have handled), the customers themselves have their own **Apple developer/iTunes Connect Account**, they will assign the **developer role** for the company that helps them to develop the app.